# Move from one tab to another using actionButton when then name of the tab is dynamic

Tags: r, shiny

How can I move from one tab to another using `actionButton()` when then name of the tab is dynamic in a `shiny` app?

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(
  tabsetPanel(
    id="inTabset",
    tabPanel("Tab 1",textInput("name","Name"),actionButton("switch_tab", "Go to the third tab")
    ),
    tabPanel("Tab 2", "there!"),
    tabPanel(textOutput("TAB3")))
  
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  observeEvent(input$switch_tab, {
    updateTabsetPanel(session, "inTabset",selected = "Tab 3")
  })
  output$TAB3<-renderText({
    if(input$name==""){
      "Tab 3"
    }
    else{
        paste(input$name)
    }
      
    
    
  })
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `tabPanel`'s `value` parameter:

From `?tabPanel`:

> **value** - The value that should be sent when tabsetPanel reports that this tab is selected. If omitted and tabsetPanel has an id, then
> the title will be used.

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(tabsetPanel(
  id = "inTabset",
  tabPanel(
    "Tab 1",
    textInput("name", "Name"),
    actionButton("switch_tab", "Go to the third tab")
  ),
  tabPanel("Tab 2", "there!"),
  tabPanel(textOutput("TAB3"), value = "TAB3")
))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$switch_tab, {
    updateTabsetPanel(session, "inTabset", selected = "TAB3")
  })
  
  output$TAB3 <- renderText({
    if (input$name == "") {
      "Tab 3"
    } else{
      paste(input$name)
    }
  })
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```